# Apply animation sequentially to multiple views

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I have an activity with 3 views (`buttonViews`) in a vertical linear layout. I am generating (inflating) these views dynamically. I want to apply an animation such that, on activity start, the first buttons slide in -> 100 ms delay -> second button slide in -> 100 ms delay -> Third button slide in.

**Attempt**

I tried implementing it in this way:

```
private void setMainButtons() {
    ArrayList<String> dashboardTitles = DashboardUtils.getDashboardTitles();
    ArrayList<Integer> dashboardIcons = DashboardUtils.getDashboardIcons();

    final ViewGroup root = findViewById(R.id.button_container);

    for (int i = 0; i < (dashboardTitles.size() < dashboardIcons.size() ? dashboardTitles.size() : dashboardIcons.size()); i++){
        final View buttonView = DashboardButtonInflater.getDashboardButton(root, dashboardTitles.get(i), dashboardIcons.get(i), this);
        if (buttonView == null) continue;
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
        root.addView(buttonView);
        animateBottomToTop(buttonView, (long) (i*50)); // Calling method to animate buttonView
    }
}

//The function that adds animation to buttonView, with a delay.
private void animateBottomToTop(final View buttonView,long delay) {
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    animationSet.addAnimation(bottomToTop);
    animationSet.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animationSet.setStartOffset(delay);
    buttonView.setAnimation(animationSet);
}
```

**Result:**

The above method waits for the total delay of all the views and at the end, aminates all the views together. I can guess the culprit here is the thread. The dealy is actually stopping the UI thread from doing any animation. I could be wrong though.

I also tried running the animation code inside

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){...}).run()
```

but that didn't work either.

**Expectations:**

Can somebody help me achieve the one-by-one animation on `buttonView`? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animations are statefull objects, you should not use the same instance multiple times simultaneously. In your case the `bottomToTop` and `fadeIn` animations are shared between the animation sets. When the set starts (`initialize()` is called) it will set the start offset of its children.

For example the method could look like :

```
//The function that adds animation to buttonView, with a delay.
private void animateBottomToTop(final View buttonView,long delay) {
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    // create new instances of the animations each time
    animationSet.addAnimation(createBottomToTop());
    animationSet.addAnimation(createFadeIn());
    animationSet.setStartOffset(delay);
    buttonView.setAnimation(animationSet);
}
```

Comment: This didn't give the result I wanted but the answer is what I was looking for. Perfect and very accurate. I will wait for a couple of days if anybody else wants to answer or will mark this correct. Thank you.

Comment: @SrujanBarai: This solution is not working for me. How did you solved it? Please share

Answer (score 5):

The problem might be easily solved with [Transitions API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/transition/TransitionManager). Having declared a root layout with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/content_frame"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Then inside activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var content: LinearLayout
    private var counter = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        content = findViewById(R.id.content_frame)
        // wait this view to be laid out and only then start adding and animating views
        content.post { addNextChild() }
    }

    private fun addNextChild() {
        // terminal condition
        if (counter >= 3) return
        ++counter

        val button = createButton()
        val slide = Slide()
        slide.duration = 500
        slide.startDelay = 100
        slide.addListener(object : TransitionListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
                addNextChild()
            }
        })
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(content, slide)
        content.addView(button)
    }

    private fun createButton(): Button {
        val button = Button(this)
        button.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        button.text = "button"
        return button
    }

}
```

This chunk of code will result in following output:

[image]

You can adjust animation and delay times respectively.

---

If you want following behavior:

[image]

Then you can use following code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var content: LinearLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        content = findViewById(R.id.content_frame)
        content.post { addChildren() }
    }

    private fun addChildren() {
        val button1 = createButton()
        val button2 = createButton()
        val button3 = createButton()

        val slide1 = Slide()
        slide1.duration = 500
        slide1.addTarget(button1)

        val slide2 = Slide()
        slide2.duration = 500
        slide2.startDelay = 150
        slide2.addTarget(button2)

        val slide3 = Slide()
        slide3.duration = 500
        slide3.startDelay = 300
        slide3.addTarget(button3)

        val set = TransitionSet()
        set.addTransition(slide1)
        set.addTransition(slide2)
        set.addTransition(slide3)

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(content, set)
        content.addView(button1)
        content.addView(button2)
        content.addView(button3)
    }

    private fun createButton(): Button {
        val button = Button(this)
        button.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        button.text = "button"
        return button
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to sound rude but if I ask a question in Java, I definitely expect an answer in Java. Anyways, I appreciate you to have taken time to actually run the code and post the results. Tho, this won't give the results I wanted. You are calling the `addNextButton()` inside the `onTransitionEnd()` which will wait for previous anim to end. What if my duration of each anim is 500 and want them to execute at a delay of 100 ms?

Answer (score 0):

Create method, which will accept Any number of `Animation` to invoke one after another. Just as example.

```
private void playOneAfterAnother(@NonNull Queue<Animation> anims) {
     final Animation next = anims.poll();

     /* You can set any other paramters, 
     like delay, for each next   Playing view, if any of course */

     next.addListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator a) {
                if (!anim.isEmpty()) {
                    playOneAfterAnother(anims);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator a) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator a) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator a) {
            }
        });
     next.play();
}
```

Or with delay for animations, it's easy too.

```
private void playOneAfterAnother(@NonNull Queue<Animation> anims, 
                  long offsetBetween, int nextIndex) {
     final Animation next = anims.poll();

     /* You can set any other paramters, 
     like delay, for each next   Playing view, if any of course */

     next.setStartOffset(offsetBetween * nextIndex);
     next.play();

     if (!anim.isEmpty()) {
         playOneAfterAnother(anims, 
              offsetBetween, nextIndex +1);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you need to use is AnimatorSet instead of AnimationSet. The AnimatorSet API allows you to choreograph animations in two ways:
1. PlaySequentially
2. PlayTogether
using the apis:

```
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
animatorSet.playSequentially(anim1, anim2, anim3, ...);
animatorSet.playTogether(anim1, anim2, anim3, ...);
```

You can further add delays to your animation using

```
animatorSet.setStartDelay();
```

Visit the complete API docs here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I Use This Code And its work correctly
Hope to help you

// first put your views in an array with name arrayViews

```
 final int[] time = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayViews.size(); i++) {
        Animation zoom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        zoom.setDuration(250);
        zoom.setStartOffset(time[0] += 250);
        arrayViews.get(i).startAnimation(zoom);
        arrayViews.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```